# find and delete gaps in date order within different IDs

Tags: r, sorting, difference, days

i have a dataframe containing different IDs and obervations from continuus days. If there where no data for one ID for a few days in a row, I want to delete them.

I use the `diff(days)` function to show how the differences between days are but I just can do this for one ID.

My df looks like this:

```
  ani_id_year       days
1  ID468_2006 2006-04-01
2  ID468_2006 2006-04-02
3  ID468_2006 2006-04-03
4  ID468_2006 2006-04-04
5  ID468_2006 2006-04-05
6  ID599_2006 2006-03-06
7  ID599_2006 2006-03-14
8  ID599_2006 2006-03-15
9  ID599_2006 2006-03-16
```

so i can see, that there is a gap in ID599_2006 for 7 days and I want to remove it automatically if the gab is =<7. As I have hundreds of IDs, I cannot do this manually.

Maybe you can help me, thanks a lot!

Best, Christian

Comment: The question is not very clear: Do you want to remove all rows with the same ID if there is a gap or do you only want to remove the row  `ID599_2006;        2006-03-06 `. Also, it's best if you post at least part of your data with `dput`, so that the example runs "out-of-the-box".

Comment: Hi, i am sorry for missunderstanding, if there is a gap larger than x, than i want to delete the whole  id. I will try your and all the Other solutions tomorrow thanks for fantastic help! I will Check out dput and try to run it next time to make ist more easy i am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. `base` solution**

```
subset(df, !ani_id_year %in% ani_id_year[c(F, diff(days) > 7)])
```

---

**2. `dplyr` solution**

```
library(dplyr)
```

- ***option 1***

  ```
  df %>%
    filter(!ani_id_year %in% ani_id_year[c(F, diff(days) > 7)])
  ```
- ***option 2***

  ```
  df %>%
    group_by(ani_id_year) %>%
    filter(!any(diff(days) > 7))
  ```

---

***Output***

```
#   ani_id_year       days
# 1  ID468_2006 2006-04-01
# 2  ID468_2006 2006-04-02
# 3  ID468_2006 2006-04-03
# 4  ID468_2006 2006-04-04
# 5  ID468_2006 2006-04-05
```

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(ani_id_year = c("ID468_2006", "ID468_2006", "ID468_2006", 
"ID468_2006", "ID468_2006", "ID599_2006", "ID599_2006", "ID599_2006", 
"ID599_2006"), days = structure(c(13239, 13240, 13241, 13242, 
13243, 13213, 13221, 13222, 13223), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to remove all entries per ID, this would be an approach.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(ani_id_year = c("ID468_2006", "ID468_2006", "ID468_2006", 
                                     "ID468_2006", "ID468_2006", "ID599_2006", "ID599_2006", "ID599_2006", 
                                     "ID599_2006"), days = c("2006-04-01", "2006-04-02", "2006-04-03", 
                                                             "2006-04-04", "2006-04-05", "2006-03-06", "2006-03-14", "2006-03-15", 
                                                             "2006-03-16")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                               "data.frame"))
data <- as_tibble(df) %>% 
  mutate(days = as.Date(days))

data %>% group_by(ani_id_year) %>% 
  mutate(difference = as.numeric(days - lag(days))) %>% 
  mutate(to_delete = ifelse(max(difference, na.rm = TRUE) <= 7,
                            "keep", "remove")) %>% 
  filter(to_delete == "keep")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Groups:   ani_id_year [1]
#>   ani_id_year days       difference to_delete
#>   <chr>       <date>          <dbl> <chr>    
#> 1 ID468_2006  2006-04-01         NA keep     
#> 2 ID468_2006  2006-04-02          1 keep     
#> 3 ID468_2006  2006-04-03          1 keep     
#> 4 ID468_2006  2006-04-04          1 keep     
#> 5 ID468_2006  2006-04-05          1 keep
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think the id which should be removed is `ID599`, not `ID468`.

Comment: Yes, my bad. "keep" and "remove" were in the wrong order. I have edited the answer. However, some better solutions have been posted below.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[!any(diff(days) > 7)], (ani_id_year)]
#  ani_id_year       days
#1:  ID468_2006 2006-04-01
#2:  ID468_2006 2006-04-02
#3:  ID468_2006 2006-04-03
#4:  ID468_2006 2006-04-04
#5:  ID468_2006 2006-04-05
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ani_id_year = c("ID468_2006", "ID468_2006", "ID468_2006", 
"ID468_2006", "ID468_2006", "ID599_2006", "ID599_2006", "ID599_2006", 
"ID599_2006"), days = structure(c(13239, 13240, 13241, 13242, 
13243, 13213, 13221, 13222, 13223), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```